# Python - Login form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, authentication

I want to get the contents of a site 'https://xxxxxx/login.htmx'. In the html code there is a JS-script like this:

```
<script language="javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
$('#BTN_ACCEDI').linkbutton({plain:false});
$('#BTN_ACCEDI').click(function(){customSubmitLogin();});
$('#j_password').validatebox({required:true,validType:'length[1,80]' });
$('#j_username').validatebox({required:true,validType:'length[1,80]'});     
$('#imp_num').validatebox({required:true,validType:'length[1,5]'});     
 $('#j_username').focus();
});</script>
```

Searching on SO I've found some clues that brought me to this:

```
payload = {'j_username':'______',
       'j_password':'______',
       'imp_num':'_____'}
url = 'https://xxxx/login.htmx'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, data=payload)
```

But when I try `r.text` it gives me the original html page, not the one after the login.

Can you help me? Is it useful to know that the URL after the successful login is the same?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, but working example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean with working example.
With the code I've provided, I cannot extract the html content. What can I add?

Comment: I mean with imports an so on. I can't get if the `requests.Session()` you use is from the standard lib or not!

Comment: unless you share the url there won't be much anyone can do

Comment: The url is https://www.sic.ania.it/login.htmx
The request is from the standard lib. Thank you!

Comment: @linusg [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) is a very popular python package for making and reading http requests

Answer (score 0):

You need more form data:

```
import requests

data = {"dispatch": "toWelcomePage",
        "j_username": "username",
        "j_password": "youpass",
        "imp_num": "num",
        "enteSel": "num"}
with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.post("https://www.sic.ania.it/login.htmx", data=data)
```

If you look open up developer tools you can see what gets posted when you submit from the browser:

[image]

Comment: What is the "dispatch" form? What should I write under it?

Comment: all you need to add yourself are the last four values

Comment: Sadly it doesn't change anything. When I type `r.text` it always shows the same html page.

Comment: Double check that your are actually successfully authenticated.  A failed authentication will likely redisplay the login page.